# Progressively find most frequent item in list in R

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, time-series, data.table

I would like to go through a list, and check to see if that item is the most frequent item in the list up until that point. The solution I currently have is incredibly slow compared to Python. Is there an effective way to speed it up?

```
   dat<-data.table(sample(1:50,10000,replace=T))
   k<-1
   correct <- 0  # total correct predictions
   for (i in 2:(nrow(dat)-1)) {
      if (dat[i,V1] %in% dat[1:(i-1),.N,by=V1][order(-N),head(.SD,k)][,V1]) {
         correct <- correct + 1
      }
   }
```

More generally, I would eventually like to see if an item is one of the k most 
frequent items up until a point, or if it has one of the k highest values up until a point.

For comparison, here is a very fast implementation in Python:

```
dat=[random.randint(1,50) for i in range(10000)]
correct=0
k=1
list={}

for i in dat:
    toplist=heapq.nlargest(k,list.iteritems(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    toplist=[j[0] for j in toplist]
    if i in toplist:
        correct+=1
    if list.has_key(i):
        list[i]=list[i]+1
    else:
        list[i]=1
```

Comment: Where is the `list`?

Comment: @Khashaa it's a one-dimensional data table `dat`

Comment: Mind to share your Python solution?

Comment: How would you resolve ties?

Comment: @MaratTalipov one step at a time...

Comment: Well, no surprise that the python solution is faster--it does not count frequencies and sort them every time anew. I am wondering if there is anything like `heapq` in R.

Comment: @MaratTalipov please try for yourself, it's not that simple. i have tried using a dictionary (keyed data.table) to keep track of counts and maintaining a running list of only the top 5 items. it does not help.

Comment: Could you show (and rationalize) the expected output for `dat <- data.table(c(1,2,2,1,1))`?

Comment: In OP's solution, if condition is little corrupted. Setting `dat[i,V1] %in% dat[1:(i-1),.N,by=V1][order(-N),head(.SD,k)]$V1` will fix it

Comment: @MaratTalipov ideally there should be two ways to breaks ties: keep the most recent to reach N, or keep the first to reach N.

Comment: What is the explanation for @MaratTalipov's example?

Comment: @Khashaa there is no correct answer, but ideally it should be parameterized-- see my comment above yours

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've got so far (my solution is f3):

```
set.seed(10)
dat<-data.table(sample(1:3,100,replace=T))
k<-1

f3 <- function(dat) {
    correct <- 0  # total correct predictions
    vf <- factor(dat$V1)
    v <- as.integer(vf) 
    tabs <- integer(max(v))
    for (i in 2:(nrow(dat)-1)) {
        tabs[v[i-1]] <- tabs[v[i-1]] + 1
        #print(tabs)
        #print(v[1:i])
        if (match(v[i],order(tabs,decreasing = T))<=k) {
            correct <- correct + 1
        }
        #print(correct)
        #print('')

    }
    correct
}

f1 <- function(dat) {
    correct <- 0  # total correct predictions
    for (i in 2:(nrow(dat)-1)) {

        if (dat[i,V1] %in% dat[1:(i-1),.N,by=V1][order(-N),head(.SD,k)]) {
            correct <- correct + 1
        }

    }
    correct
}

library(rbenchmark)

print(f1(dat)==f3(dat))

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f1(dat),f3(dat),replications=10)
```

The benchmark results:

```
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 f1(dat)           10   2.939  163.278     2.931    0.008          0         0
2 f3(dat)           10   0.018    1.000     0.018    0.000          0         0
```

are encouraging, but `f3` has two problems:

1. It doesn't always provide the same answer as OP's algorithm because the ties are treated differently,
2. There is a lot of room for improvement, because `tabs` are sorted every time anew.

Comment: `print(f1(dat)==f3(dat))` is `FALSE`?

Comment: @Khashaa, yes, it's `FALSE`

Answer (score 3):

The condition is automatically true up until k+1 values have been observed:

```
startrow <- dat[,list(.I,.GRP),by=V1][.GRP==k+1]$.I[1]
correct  <- rep(0L,length(v))
correct[1:(startrow-1)] <- 1L
```

You can precompute the number of appearances a value of `V1` has had so far:

```
ct   <- dat[,ct:=1:.N,by=V1]$ct
```

During the loop, we can check if the kth most frequent value is knocked out by the current value.

1. Grab the first k values and their counts up until `startrow`: `topk <- sort(tapply(ct[1:(startrow-1)],v[1:(startrow-1)],max))`
2. Note that the first item is the threshold for joining the top-k club: `thresh   <- unname(topk[1])`
3. Loop from `startrow` to `length(v)`, updating `correct` (here a vector, not a running sum) whenever the threshold is met; and updating the top-k club if the threshold is met *and* the value is not already in the club.

---

---

**That's it; the rest is just details.** Here's my function:

```
ff <- function(dat){
    vf   <- factor(dat$V1)
    v    <- as.integer(vf) 
    ct   <- dat[,ct:=1:.N,by=V1]$ct
    n    <- length(v)

    ct <- setNames(ct,v)

    startrow <- dat[,list(.I,.GRP),by=V1][.GRP==k+1]$.I[1]
    topk     <- sort(tapply(ct[1:(startrow-1)],v[1:(startrow-1)],max))
    thresh   <- unname(topk[1])

    correct  <- rep(0L,n)
    correct[1:(startrow-1)] <- 1L
    for (i in startrow:n) {
        cti = ct[i]
        if ( cti >= thresh ){
            correct[i] <- 1L
            if ( cti > thresh & !( names(cti) %in% names(topk) ) ){
                topk    <- sort(c(cti,topk))[-1]
                thresh  <- unname(topk[1])
            }
        }
    }
    sum(correct)
}
```

It is very fast, but differs from @MaratTalipov's and the OP's in its results:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.table(sample(1:50,10000,replace=T))
k   <- 5

f1(dat) # 1012
f3(dat) # 1015
ff(dat) # 1719
```

Here's my benchmark (excluding the OP's approach as encapsulated in `f1()`, since I'm impatient):

```
> benchmark(f3(dat),ff(dat),replications=10)[,1:5]
     test replications elapsed relative user.self
1 f3(dat)           10    2.68    2.602      2.67
2 ff(dat)           10    1.03    1.000      1.03
```

My function gives more matches than @Marat's and the OP's because it allows ties at the threshold to count as "correct", while theirs only count matches for at most k values selected by whatever algorithm R's `order` function uses.

Comment: +1 because I think this is the right idea, but smth is wrong with your implementation, I get `Error in 1:(startrow - 1) : argument of length 0`

Comment: @eddi: Hm, that's weird; I guess `startrow` should always be greater than 1, so long as `dat$V1` has more than one value. I noticed something else wrong with my solution as well -- it doesn't update the threshold as often as it should. I figure I'll revisit it if I'm clear on what the desired treatment of ties is; and leave it up anyways, so that the other answerers can borrow the useful parts (code for the `topk` and `ct`) to speed up their solutions.

Answer (score 3):

**[New Solution]**

There is a lightning fast and very easy `dplyr` solution for `k=1`. The `fC1` below treats the ties equally, i.e., no tie-breaking. You'll see that you can impose any tie-breaking rule on it. And, it is really fast.

```
library(dplyr)
fC1 <- function(dat){
   dat1 <- tbl_df(dat) %>%
       group_by(V1) %>% 
       mutate(count=row_number()-1)  %>%  ungroup() %>% slice(2:n()-1) %>% 
       filter(count!=0) %>%
       mutate(z=cummax(count)) %>% 
       filter(count==z)  
   z <- dat1$z
   length(z)
}

set.seed(1234)
dat<-data.table(sample(1:5000, 100000, replace=T))
system.time(a1 <- fC1(dat))[3] #returns 120
elapsed 
   0.04 
system.time(a3m <- f3m(dat, 1))[3] #returns 29, same to the Python result which runs about 60s
elapsed 
  89.72 
system.time(a3 <- f3(dat, 1))[3] #returns 31. 
elapsed 
  95.07
```

***You can freely impose some tie-breaking rule on the result of `fC1`*** to arrive at a different solutions. For instance, in order to arrive at `f3m` or `f3` solutions, we restrict the selection of some rows as follows

```
fC1_ <- function(dat){
    b <- tbl_df(dat) %>% 
        group_by(V1) %>% 
        mutate(count=row_number()-1) %>%
        ungroup()  %>% 
        mutate(L=cummax(count+1))# %>% 
    b1 <- b %>% slice(2:(n()-1)) %>% 
        group_by(L) %>% 
        slice(1) %>% 
        filter(count+1>=L& count>0)
    b2 <- b %>% group_by(L) %>% 
        slice(1)  %>%
        ungroup() %>%  
        select(-L)  %>%  
        mutate(L=count)
    semi_join(b1, b2, by=c("V1", "L")) %>% nrow
}


set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.table(sample(1:50,10000,replace=T))
fC1_(dat)
#[1] 218
f3m(dat, 1)
#[1] 217
f3(dat, 1)
#[1] 218
```

and for earlier example

```
set.seed(1234)
dat<-data.table(sample(1:5000, 100000, replace=T))
system.time(fC1_(dat))[3];fC1_(dat)
#elapsed 
#   0.05 
#[1] 29
```

Somehow, I couldn't extend the solution for general `k>1`, so I resorted to Rcpp.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> countrank(std::vector<int> y, int k) {
    std::vector<int> v(y.begin(), y.begin() + k);
    std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::vector<int> count(y.size());
    for(int i=0; i < y.size(); i++){
        if(y[i]==0){count[i]=0;}
        else{
            v.push_back(y[i]); std::push_heap(v.begin(), v.end()); 
            std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end()); v.pop_back();
            std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find (v.begin(), v.end(), y[i]);
            if (it != v.end()) {count[i]=1;};
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

For `k=1`, it is worth noting that `fC1` is at least as fast as the following Rcpp version `fCpp`.

```
 fCpp <- function(dat, k) {
    dat1 <- tbl_df(dat) %>% 
        group_by(V1) %>% 
        mutate(count=row_number())
    x <- dat1$V1
    y <- dat1$count-1
    z <- countrank(-y, k)
    sum(z[2:(nrow(dat)-1)])
}
```

Again, you can impose any tie-breaking rule with minimal effort.

---

**[`f3, f3m` functions]**

`f3` is from @Marat Talipov and `f3m` is some amendment to it (seems superfluous though).

```
f3m <- function(dat, k){
    n <- nrow(dat)
    dat1 <- tbl_df(dat) %>% 
        group_by(V1) %>% 
        mutate(count=row_number())
    x <- dat1$V1
    y <- dat1$count
    rank <- rep(NA, n)
    tablex <- numeric(max(x))
    for(i in 2:(n-1)){
        if(y[i]==1){rank[i]=NA} #this condition was originally missing
        else{
            tablex[x[i-1]] = y[i-1]
            rank[i]=match(x[i], order(tablex, decreasing = T))
        }
    }
    rank <- rank[2:(n-1)] 
    sum(rank<=k, na.rm=T)
 }
```

---

Refer to the edit history for earlier solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about this solution:

```
# unique values
unq_vals <- sort(dat[, unique(V1)])

# cumulative count for each unique value by row
cum_count <- as.data.table(lapply(unq_vals, function(x) cumsum(dat$V1==x)))

# running ranking for each unique value by row
cum_ranks <- t(apply(-cum_count, 1, rank, ties.method='max'))
```

Now the rank of (e.g.) the 2nd unique value as of the 8th observation is stored in:

```
cum_ranks[8, 2]
```

You can get the rank of each item by row (and present it in a readable table) like this. If `rank` <= k for row i, then the i-th item of `V1` is among the k-th most frequent items as of observation i.

```
dat[, .(V1, rank=sapply(1:length(V1), function(x) cum_ranks[x, V1[x]]))]
```

The first code block takes only 0.6883929 secs on my machine (according to a crude `now <- Sys.time(); [code block in here]; Sys.time() - now` timing), with `dat <- data.table(sample(1:50, 10000, replace=T))`

Comment: How about the case of `dat<-data.table(1:10000)`?

Comment: right, but my example has 10000 *different* elements

Comment: Oh, I see. With your `dat` (10,000 rows and 10,000 different elements), it ran in 41.41968 secs.

Comment: On my laptop, it takes about 50 secs. My solution ran in ~10s, and python solution took about 8 secs.

Comment: Also, this solution can be improved significantly using data.table's `frank` in place of base `rank`. Thanks @MaratTalipov and @arvi1000, I'll look at these again in the morning

Comment: Neat, but your solution is running for a single value of k, right @Marat? If you are interested in all of `k in 1:50`, seems like you'd need `f3()` 50 times

Comment: my solution checks if `i`-th value is within `k` most frequently met values, which is the same as the OP's R solution. I like your idea about ranks, because I think it is the proper way to treat this problem. Perhaps, your solution runs in longer time because it has to sort every row anew, i.e. without using the information that it differs from the previous row only by one element (my solution has the same problem). Besides, your solution has to deal with potentially huge data structures, which might have some impact on performance.